# Mongoose Cannot Update Instead Create A New Array

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mongoose

I cannot update my collection even without encountering any error. Can someone help?
Please I am troubleshooting this for like 3 hours now.

```
const product_id = req.body.cartItems.product_id;
      const item = cart.cartItems.find(c => c.product_id == product_id);
      if (item) {
        Cart.findOneAndUpdate({ "user": req.user._id, "cartItems.product_id" : product_id }, {
            "$set": {
              "cartItems.$":{
                ...req.body.cartItems.quantity,
                quantity: item.quantity + req.body.cartItems.quantity
              }
            }
          })
          .exec((error, _cart) => {
          if (error) return res.status(400).json({ error });
          if (_cart) {
            return res.status(201).json({ _cart });
          }
        });
```

The MODEL:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const cartSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    user: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User', required: true},
    cartItems: [
        {
            product_id: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Product', required: true}, // This foreign key to product _id
            quantity: {type: Number,required: true},
            price: {type: Number, required: true}
        }
    ]
}, {timestamps: true});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Cart', cartSchema);
```

Comment: Can you provide your mongoose model?

Comment: You can edit your post and insert it there, too!

Comment: You may now check it @stefOb sorry I'm still a newbie on stackoverflow

Comment: I´ve added a solution, I hope it solves your issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the $[] operator to update all documents inside the cartItems array matching your filter criteria. This operator acts like a placeholder for all items in the array. Considering your coding it would be something like this:

```
Cart.findOneAndUpdate({ "user": req.user._id, "cartItems.product_id" : product_id }, {
        "$set": {
          "cartItems.$[].quantity": item.quantity + req.body.cartItems.quantity
        }
      }).exec(...)
```

Comment: I'll test this thank you so much! Atleast I have the idea now

Answer (score 0):

```
const product = req.body.cartItems.product;
const items = cart.cartItems.find((c) => c.product == product);

if (items) {
  Cart.findOneAndUpdate(
    {
      user: req.user._id,
      'cartItems.product': product,
    },
    {
      $set: {
        'cartItems.$': {
          ...req.body.cartItems,
          quantity: items.quantity + req.body.cartItems.quantity,
        },
      },
    }
  ).exec((error, _cart) => {
    if (error) return res.status(400).json({ error });

    if (_cart) {
      res.status(200).json({
        cart: _cart,
      });
    }
  });
}
```